# Why won't my taxonomy query show up?

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, theme-development

I'm attempting to display **posts** from a **'Uncategorized'** category under a custom taxonomy called **'Reviews'** but without much luck.

I'm using `get_template_part('loop','review')` to call `loop-review.php` which contains my taxonomy loop but for some reason, nothing will show up. What gives?

Here are the contents of `loop-review.php`...

```
<div class="row no-margin detail">
    <p class="title"><span>reviews</span></p>
    <?php 

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'review',
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'terms'     => 'uncategorized'
            )
        )
    ); $review_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
    <?php if ($review_query->have_posts()): ?>
            <?php while ($review_query->have_posts()): $review_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <p class="quote">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                            <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                    </p>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <!-- end of the loop -->
                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php else:  ?>
                    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

I call `get_template_part('loop','review')` inside my my `category.php`...

```
<?php 

get_header(); 

if (is_category('portfolio')): 
    get_template_part('single','portfolio'); 
    get_template_part('loop','review');
else: 
    get_template_part("single","blog");
endif; 

get_footer(); 

?>
```

Lastly, here is the code from my `functions.php`...

```
add_action('init', 'build_taxonomies', 0);
function build_taxonomies(){
        register_taxonomy('review', 'post', array(
            'hierarchical'    => 'true',
            'label'           => 'Reviews',
            'query_var'       => 'true',
            'rewrite'         => 'true'
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no methods `the_content()` or `the_title()` of your query object.

These:

```
$review_query->the_content();
$review_query->the_title();
```

should just be

```
the_content();
the_title();
```

If you had [debugging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) you would see an error informing you of this.

Comment: Thanks but still no posts. I've updated my code to reflect your feedback. Also, I've enabled debugging and am not receiving any errors?

Comment: are you sure there are posts that match the query? `var_dump($review_query);` and inspect the query parameters, make sure there isn't a filter of some sort altering the query.

Comment: I've tried that already. I have two posts in 'Uncategorized' category in 'Review' but `var_dump` returns nothing.

Comment: `var_dump` *after* the query is run is empty?

Comment: I tried putting it after the query and in the loop. Nothing was dumped.

Comment: are you sure your `loop-review.php` file is being loaded at all? If it is being loaded, and you don't see your `Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.` message, then it makes no sense that `$review_query` would be empty.

Comment: `get_template_part("single","porfolio")` gets loaded, why wouldn't `get_template_part('loop','review')` be loaded? I've updated my post to include the `category.php` file.

Comment: have you confirmed that it's *not* being loaded? is it in the root of your theme directory?

Comment: It is in the root of my directory.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I see that your query is calling for `'post_type' => 'page'` while the taxonomy is registered on the `post` object type. Changing the post type to `post` (`'post_type' => 'post'`) should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work. I've updated my code.